# matplotlib - can't plot without errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, lines

I'm new to matplotlib and I'm learning how to work with it. With my code I'm trying to plot multiple scatterplots, but there are always unwanted lines that I can't get rid off.

See image attached to this post.

Here is my Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import cluster

iris = datasets.load_iris()

for i in range(1,7):
    kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=i).fit(iris.data)
    Centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    plot_nr = 230+i
    plt.subplot(plot_nr)
    text = str(i) + ' Cluster'
    plt.scatter(iris.data[:,0], iris.data[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_)
    plt.scatter(Centers[:,0], Centers[:,1], c='r', s=150, marker='*')
    plt.title(text)

plt.savefig('Iris.png')
plt.show()
```

I'm thankful for every suggestion!

Thanks,
Thomas

Plot with unwanted lines

[image: Plot with unwanted lines]

Comment: Since you also seem to be new to Stackoverflow, please read [ask] and [mcve]. The code you show is not runnable, so one cannot reproduce this funky behaviour and hence cannot suggest a solution. Creating a [mcve] may be a little bit of work, finding out which minimal set of data would produce this, but it's worth doing in case you want an answer here and also for yourself to be able to debug things.

Comment: i don't know if i can edit his post to make the code runnable, but it's pretty easy to make it so

Comment: @Thomas_ to satisfy ImportantOfBeingErnest's request, add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from sklearn import datasets;
from sklearn import cluster;

iris = datasets.load_iris()` to the top of your code and it should be runnable for all. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit first line `plt.subplots(231, figsize=(18,12))` and replace `231` by `2, 3,`
231 creates a cell between the two rows. probably repeated 6 times

(and it should be way faster)

Comment: good catch. it's not clear what you mean "edit" and "type 231", but using your recommendation I commented out (or deleted) that line, and noticed it does resolve the issue, thus upvoted +1

Comment: Thank you bobrobbob, you helped me a lot!  Kind regards, Thomas